# NUnit assertions in production code

Tags: c#, asp.net, testing, nunit

I am trying to find best practices for having assertions in production code but I am surprised at how little information I have found.

First is it generally acceptable or not to have assert statements in production code?

Second I read that the built in Debug.Assert for .NET essentially automatically disables itself for production code and only actually runs in development environments. Is that true and does NUnit also have this functionality built in?

For example if I have the following in production code would the assertion be ignored?

```
var sortedActuals = actuals.OrderByDescending(a =>
                    {
                        Assert.That(a.GLPeriodDateTime, Is.Not.Null, "GLPeriodDateTime was null when it should not be");
                        return a.GLPeriodDateTime.Value;
                    })
```

Comment: Have you tried it? What was the result?

Comment: I wouldn't use NUnit assertions in production code. If you want checking you can raise your own exceptions or use code contracts. In this case it looks like the class for `a` should ensure `GLPeriodDateTime` is never null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use NUnit assertions in production code. The NUnit assertions always throw an exception if the assertion fails. NUnit does not check if it is running in Debug or Release (Production). NUnit assertions are also designed to be used within NUnit tests.

For assertions in your actual code, you should use `Debug.Assert`. It is less featured, but it gets compiled out in Release mode so won't crash your app running in production.

Answer (score 5):

NUnit Assertions have to function in release builds because release builds have to be tested. You shouldn't include NUnit assertions in your production code for several reasons.

1. NUnit assertions (as well as Debug.Assert) are intended to detect problems in **your** code. Bad data provided to your application is part of the normal application flow and should be detected and dealt with by your production code.
2. The assertions are intended to run under the control of NUnit, which knows what the results mean. For example, some assertions throw an exception upon failure and others don't. You would need to know the difference to make any valid use of it.
3. There are other, well-established ways of dealing with bad data, including exception handling, custom error messages, etc.
4. Most likely, you are trying to use the NUnit constraint syntax separate from NUnit testing. It's a nice syntax and several folks have asked us to split it off as a separate package. If we had done that, you could use it, but unfortunately we haven't yet.

Comment: Hi Charlie,
So is it bad in general to deploy NUnit projects to production environments/servers? Should we only test on our local builds, then publish the project to production without NUnit? Or are there cases when exporting your NUnit testing project to production would be appropriate?

Comment: IMO I think it's OK to deploy NUnit to any server on which you want to run tests. I don't think you want to reference NUnit from any production code, however. In particular, this would be a problem in safety-critical applications for which NUnit is not certified. NUnit is a tool for testing production software but not intended to become part of that software.

Answer (score 1):

I'll start with the second question.  No, the assertion would not be ignored.  In the build configuration for C# projects you can specify that a build ignores the DEBUG constant.  This is how Debug.Assert statements are removed (Visual Studio gives you a build configuration set up this way by default).

As for your first question, I would say it is unacceptable to have NUnit assertions in production code.  Ask yourself, what advantage does using as assertion have over an exception or some other error state?

If `GLPeriodDateTime` can be null through no fault of the user, perhaps more thorough testing is needed prior to release to fix this issue.  If the user is at fault, there are better ways (such as an exception) to inform the user of the error.  Assertions are meant for developer use.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I don't anticipate it to ever be null because the fields it pulls from are required on the users input. I would still like a check for the developers though because some data is imported from a legacy system and while it "should" always have that data it would be unwise not to check for it. I think I will use the built in assertions to let the developers know but not bother the users.